# Can't successfully clone XMLReader (Unexpected EOF)

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization, clone, xmlreader

I have a really strange problem with XMLReader/XMLTextReader classes.

I have a simple file load:

```
public void First()
{
    XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(@"C:\MyXMLFile.xml");
    XmlReader readerToSerialize;
    XmlReader readerToLoad;
    DuplicateReaders(reader, out readerToSerialize, out readerToLoad);
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XMLTree));
    XmlFeed = (XMLDescriptor)serializer.Deserialize(readerToSerialize);
    xmlDoc.Load(readerToLoad);
}
protected void DuplicateReaders(XmlTextReader xmlReader, out XmlReader cloneOne, out readerToLoad)
{
    XmlDocument _XmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
    MemoryStream _Stream = new MemoryStream();
    _XmlDocument.Load((XmlTextReader)xmlReader);
    _XmlDocument.Save(_Stream);
    _Stream.Position = 0L;
    cloneOne = XmlReader.Create(_Stream);
    _Stream.Position = 0L;
    cloneTwo = XmlReader.Create(_Stream);
}
```

The problem is that only one of the cloned elements read the whole file successully, the next one (xmlDoc.Load) fails always at the same place (Line 91, Character 37 with this xml file). If I directly assign to xmlDoc (i.e. clone the original element only once and asign it directly from the function):

```
public void First()
{
    XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(@"C:\MyXMLFile.xml");
    XmlReader readerToSerialize;
    DuplicateReaders(reader, out readerToSerialize);
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XMLTree));
    XmlFeed = (XMLDescriptor)serializer.Deserialize(readerToSerialize);
}
protected void DuplicateReaders(XmlTextReader xmlReader, out XmlReader cloneOne)
{
    XmlDocument _XmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
    MemoryStream _Stream = new MemoryStream();
    _XmlDocument.Load((XmlTextReader)xmlReader);
    _XmlDocument.Save(_Stream);
    _Stream.Position = 0L;
    cloneOne = XmlReader.Create(_Stream);
    _Stream.Position = 0L;
    this.xmlDoc.Load(_Stream);
}
```

I still get the same error 91/37 (Unexpected EOF), but this time in the Serializer.

My initial problem was that if I use `xmlDoc.Load(reader)` the reader instance get destroyed and I can't serialize it later on. I found the Duplicate function on the MSDN forums, but it's still a no go. What I want to achieve is quite simple:

Use only one reader and get one XmlDocument and one Serialized Class. How hard can it be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found much easier solution, instead of cloning the two readers, i just use create a second one from XmlDoc and use it to deserialize.

Answer (score 1):

You need to close the first reader before you can use the duplicate.

```
reader.Close()
```

Comment: I close the reader right after i clone it (and before i actually use its clone), but i still get "Unxpected EOF".

Comment: What line are you closing it?

Comment: Im closing the main reader, right after the Duplicate function, and the first clone, right after its being used. However the second clone gets EOF.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Just read the code again. I think it's because the second one is using the (first) TextReader to read the document, and when you close it, it is seeing EOF.

Answer (score 1):

Your both cloneOne and cloneTwo use the same underlying memory stream.

use a different MemoryStream

```
cloneTwo = XmlReader.Create(new MemoryStream(_Stream.ToArray()));
```